# App Dev Driver Limit

Tags: android, android-emulator, haxm

I've just started working with Android Studios to learn App Dev and have tried running a basic test app. I have everything installed including the HAXM but continue to receive this message:

```
    emulator: device fd:596
    HAX is not working and emulator runs in emulation mode
    emulator: The memory needed by this VM exceeds the driver limit.
    creating window 43 59 329 583
    Error accepting connection, aborting
```

I have already allotted a full gigabyte to the HAXM and still nothing has changed. When I run the emulator, it gives me the phone frame with a blank screen. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

You may want to use an emulator system image which does not require HAXM.

You can use an emulator with the **ARM image instead of HAXM provided that you installed it in the SDK manager**.

Check your SDK manager to see if you have an ARM image instead for the API level you want, then go to the AVD manager and make a virtual device using ARM as the cpu.

Comment: I do see an ARM image but I don't know how to change it so that it utilizes the ARM instead of the HAXM

Comment: You should be able to change it, probably in the same settings screen where you choose between running it on emulator or on real device via ADB. In Android Studio, it's called 'Run Configurations'.

Comment: I seem to worse at this than i thought because i can't find anything called "run configurations" and i didn't know running it on a real device was an option

Comment: @1234567power In android studio, look in the 'run' menu > 'Edit configurations' , And near the bottom , There is an option for 'target device' , where you can choose which image you want to run it with, or you can choose to run it on a USB device.